# NSURLSession Authorization with post request

Tags: objective-c, post, authorization, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

When i am trying to make a post request without (www-authorization) with NSURLSession and dataTaskWithRequest (i am using custom delegate).

It works well. (i send the request, on the server i just print echo $_POST['name'] and i get the "name" as the response.)

When i am trying to make a post request with (www-authorization) it looks like it works fine

If i enter the correct username and password i get the header with the status-code 200 and json data, if i make a mistake i get the header with the status code 401. 
On the server side i made

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');        
exit;
}
else
{
    $user = new btuser($_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"],$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    if ($user->logToDB())
    {
       header('content-type:application/json');
       header('test-login: '.$user->getname());         
       $array = array("fff"=>"tttt",
      "ddd"=>"qqqq",
      "uuuu"=>$_post['name']        
      );
      echo json_encode($array);    
    }
    else
    {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);        
    }                   
}
```

, but "post" request is lost somewhere )))... I got something like this - {"fff":"tttt","ddd":"qqqq","uuuu":null}.

All delegete's methods looks like work fine ...
the first method is

1.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:        (int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:        (int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend{  
 NSLog(@"did send body data");
}
```

2.

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task      didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
NSLog(@"challenge");
    NSURLCredential* newCredintioal;
    newCredintioal = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"testuser" password:@"testpassword" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
      [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredintioal forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,newCredintioal);
}
```

3 Then again didSendBodyData.

4

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask      didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
 {
 NSLog(@"did receive response %@", response);
 completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);

 NSURLRequest* req = dataTask.currentRequest;
 NSData* dt = [req HTTPBody];
 NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
 NSLog(@"credintials   %d     \n %@ \n %@ \n %@  ",dataTask.state, body, dataTask, req);
}
```

5

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask      didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
 NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

 NSDictionary *urlResponseDataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data      options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
 [_savedData appendData:data];

  //  NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"did receive data %@",urlResponseDataDict);
}
```

6

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task      didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
 {

 // NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

 //  NSDictionary *urlResponseDataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_savedData      options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

 NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_savedData      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"did complete with error - %@, data - %@, _saveddata - %@", error, str,      _savedData ); //, urlResponseDataDict);
 }
```

How can i make a simple data post request with authorisation (URLSession:task:task didReceiveChallenge:)?
What am i doing wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Unrelated but, 1. In `didReceiveChallenge` you don't have to call `[[challenge sender] useCredential...]`, because you're calling the completion block instead. You should only call sender's `useCredential` in conjunction with `NSURLConnection` (or `NSURLDownload`). 2. Don't parse response in `didReceiveData`, just `appendData`. Do the `NSJSONSerialization` parsing in `didCompleteWithError`. If your response was large enough, it might take multiple calls to `didReceiveData` before the app received all the data.

Comment: Thank you. I think without your comment i wouldnt realize that i am doing big mistakes in this place for a long time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably on the PHP script: `$_post` is not the same as `$_POST` (note the capitalization)

Comment: THANKS .... Its ridiculous, but now it works ))).
It was just a strange concurrence that each time i was making a php file without www-authorization header i used the correct $_POST and each time i used "www-authorization" i made $_post ....